# How i can extracte x_train and y_train from train_generator?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, cross-validation

In my CNN model I want to extract `X_train` and `y_train` from train_generator. I want to use ensemble learning, bagging and boosting to evaluate the model. the main challenge is how i can extract `X_train` and `y_train` from `train_generator` using python language.

```
 history=model.fit_generator(train_generator, 
                             steps_per_epoch=num_of_train_samples // batch_size,
                             epochs=10, validation_data=validation_generator, 
                             validation_steps=num_of_val_samples // batch_size, 
                             callbacks=callbacks)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, first of all you didn't write the piece of code declaring this train_generator.

Since it seems to be a generator in the keras way, you should be accessing X_train and y_train by looping through train_generator.

This mean that train_generator[0] will give you the first batch of pairs of X_train/y_train.

```py
x_train = []
y_train = []
for x, y in train_generator:
    x_train.append(x)
    y_train.append(y)
```

Comment: train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_data_path,
                                                    target_size=(img_rows, img_cols),
                                                    batch_size=batch_size, 
                                                    class_mode='categorical', shuffle=False)

Comment: Straight from the documentation : train_generator id "A DirectoryIterator yielding tuples of (x, y) where x is a numpy array containing a batch of images with shape (batch_size, *target_size, channels) and y is a numpy array of corresponding labels.". I'm editing my answer so that you can just paste it

Comment: I used this code to print the array but the out put is none!!!                                                   x_train = []
y_train = []
for x, y in train_generator:
    print(x_train.append(x))
    print(y_train.append(y))

Comment: You're printing the output of the function, obviously it won't work  paste exactly the code and after the for loop you can print(x_ttain) and print(y_train)

Comment: Thanks alot faucozo,,, I trying to implement ensemble learning using CNN, that is why I need x_train and y_train...If you know ensemble example, inform me please.B.Regards

Comment: You're welcome, I never tried that but you should look at https://paperswithcode.com/ there is a lot of example there. If you don't mind you can accept my answer :)

Comment: thanks alot,, your code is take alot of time and then stucked,, iam used google colab, the problem i think is the number of image(1000 img).what should i do??can i save it in csv file for example and how?

Answer (score 2):

> Compared to the answer above, this code is computational faster

```
train_generator.reset()
X_train, y_train = next(train_generator)
for i in tqdm.tqdm(range(int(train_generator.n/batch_size)-1)): 
  img, label = next(train_generator)
  X_train = np.append(X_train, img, axis=0 )
  y_train = np.append(y_train, label, axis=0)
print(X_train.shape, y_train.shape)
```

Note: You would have to install tqdm module as this helps us see the progress of extraction of our X_train and y_train.

```
pip install tqdm
```